# Get the edges for 1st and 2nd level neighbors limited by their degree

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I  would like to make a query that contains all 1st and second level neighbors from a given node. However I only want to retain a neighbor if it has at least two edges within the query (so that any node that is only connected to the rest with one edge is left out.

As a result i would obtain list of all the edges present.
I have tried the code below, which yields me the nodes im interrested in. But how do i get the edges? I tried to add them at the `WITH` command, but that didnt work.

```
MATCH (g:User)-[r:KNOWS*0..2]-(p) 
WHERE id(g)=410
WITH p as p, count(r) as rC
WHERE rC>=2
RETURN p, rC
```

I used [this](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/quickly-create-a-100k-neo4j-graph-data-model-with-cypher-only/) way of generating test data

```
WITH ["Andres","Wes","Rik","Mark","Peter","Kenny","Michael","Stefan","Max","Chris"] AS names
FOREACH (r IN range(0,800) | CREATE (:User {id:r, name:names[r % size(names)]+" "+r}));

match (u:User),(p:User)
with u,p
limit 10000
where rand() < 0.1
create (u)-[:KNOWS]->(p);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect relationships of the path:

```
MATCH path = (g:User)-[r:KNOWS*0..2]-(p) 
    WHERE id(g)=410
WITH p, 
     count(r) as rC, 
     collect( relationships(path) ) as edges
    WHERE rC>=2
RETURN p, edges, rC
```

Update:

```
MATCH path = (g:User)-[r:KNOWS*0..2]-(p) WHERE g.id=410
WITH p, 
     count(r) as rC, 
     collect( EXTRACT(x in relationships(path) | id(x)) ) as edges
    WHERE rC>=2
RETURN p, edges, rC
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me empty edges. Should I define the path variable somewhere?

Is it also possible just to get the edgelist return instead of multiple lists from each node?

Comment: @BjørnØstHansen Okay, then it will be good if you have to provide a minimum set of test input data and the desired result.

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. I have added it in the question.

Comment: @BjørnØstHansen I think the problem is that you check the internal node ID. Whereas it is necessary to check (according to the example) identifier set with properties of a node: `WHERE g.id=410` instead `WHERE id(g)=410`.

Comment: no, they still show up like this [[(empty), (empty)], [(empty), (empty)]]

Comment: @BjørnØstHansen "Empty" does not mean that there is no result - does this mean that there is no property that can be displayed. See update.

Comment: ah sorry, my bad. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What if we don't know what the relation type (KNOWS) is? How do we return 0..2 degree neighbors, including both relations and the nodes themselves, regardless of the relation type?